# Asp.net Vb.net - How to load bulk records from SQL Server database

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I created a product campaign which tie up to a lots of product. When I try to view the campaign, it took some time to load the data. I try to change to use procedure for the fastest execution time and I had no idea what value to put for `@startRowIndex` and `@pageSize`

Query and VB.NET code-behind:

```
SELECT 
    CAMPAIGN_DETAILS_PRODUCT_ID, CAMPAIGN_ID, PRODUCT_CODE, PRODUCT_NAME 
FROM 
    CAMPAIGN_DETAILS_PRODUCT
WHERE 
    CAMPAIGN_ID = @CAMPAIGN_ID

Private Sub GridViewPdtTieUp _PageIndexChanging(sender As Object, e As GridViewPageEventArgs) Handles GridViewPdtTieUp.PageIndexChanging
    GridViewPdtTieUp .PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex
    GridViewPdtTieUp .DataSource = ViewState(dtProduct)
    GridViewPdtTieUp .DataBind()
End Sub
```

Procedure:

```
SELECT
    CAMPAIGN_DETAILS_PRODUCT_ID, CAMPAIGN_ID, PRODUCT_CODE, PRODUCT_NAME
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CAMPAIGN_DETAILS_PRODUCT_ID) AS Row,
         CAMPAIGN_DETAILS_PRODUCT_ID, CAMPAIGN_ID, PRODUCT_CODE, 
         PRODUCT_NAME
     FROM 
         CAMPAIGN_DETAILS_PRODUCT) AS CampaignProductRow
WHERE
    (Row BETWEEN (@startRowIndex) AND @startRowIndex + @pageSize - 1)
    AND CAMPAIGN_ID = '1234567890'
```

Comment: plase provide some fact & figure. 'some time to load the data' when you deal with 'lots of product' is not something you can get help on. how many rows? what's the actual performance? what's the expected performance? please update the question and do not put details in the comments.

Comment: It took 2-3 minutes to load 40k and above records. Is it possible to load those records in less than a minute?